# How to perfectly bake light using GPU instead of CPU?

Tags: baking

So far, i have only been using my CPU to bake out lightmaps.
Recently i discovered that by using the GPU the speed of baking can be reduced significantly.

However, in my attempt to use my GPU to bake, the lightmaps that im getting looks terrible...

I have a created a simple scene to illustrate my problem which includes a wall, floor, ceiling and a window (i'm using the archipack addon).

The first picture shows the lightmap using the GPU

The second shows the lightmap using the CPU

[image]

[image]

Furthermore, it seems that the problem is caused when the window mesh is added to the scene.

I tried to bake using my GPU on a single wall which gave me a good result:

[image]

Does any one of you know why this window causes the black dots and very dark walls compared to the third picture?

Any help would be much appreciated :-)!